# JSON data array is appending all elements to a single <li> instead of mapping each element to its own <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to map over each element of an array and append it to its own li tag, but the data is being returned comma separated and all on the same li. Essentially I want each team's starter's id number to be mapped onto its own individual li tag. Any advice on how I can achieve this?

Here is my function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/784456593403224064/rosters',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                teamData = result.map(result => result.starters);
                teamData.forEach((starter, item) => {
                    $(`.starters-list${item}`).append('<li>'+starter+'</li>');
                });
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
    })
});
```

And here is my index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="./js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Brick Dynasty Newsletter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="main-header">Brick Dynasty Newsletter</h1>
<!-- <button class="accordion">Scoring Settings &#xbb</button>
<div class="panel">
  <ul class="accordion-list"></ul>
</div>
    <div class="league-info">
        <h1 class="rosters">Total Teams:</h1>
    </div> -->

    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- <h1 class="transaction-header">Recent Transactions</h1>
    <div class="transaction-container">
        <ul class="added">Added:</ul>
        <ul class="dropped">Dropped:</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="trending-down-container">
        <h1>Trending Down:</h1>
        <ul class="trending-down"></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="trending-up-container">
        <h1>Trending Up:</h1>
        <ul class="trending-up"></ul>
    </div> -->
    <div class="league-members-container">
        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar0" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player0"></div>
            <div id="team-name0"></div>
                <ul class="starters-list0"></ul>
            </div>
            <br><br>

        <div class="player-container">    
            <img id="avatar1" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player1"></div>
            <div id="team-name1"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list1"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>

        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar2" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player2"></div>
            <div id="team-name2"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list2"></ul>
        </div>
        <br><br>

        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar3" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player3"></div>
        <div id="team-name3"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list3"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>

        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar4" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player4"></div>
            <div id="team-name4"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list4"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>

        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar5" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player5"></div>
            <div id="team-name5"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list5"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>

        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar6" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player6"></div>
            <div id="team-name6"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list6"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>

        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar7" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player7"></div>
            <div id="team-name7"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list7"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>

        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar8" src="" alt="">
            <div id="player8"></div>        
            <div id="team-name8"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list8"></ul>
        </div> 
        <br><br>

        <div class="player-container">
            <img id="avatar9" src="" alt="">     
            <div id="player9"></div>        
            <div id="team-name9"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list9"></ul>  
        </div>    
    </div>  
</div>
<h1>What you need to know for the upcoming 2022 draft!</h1>
<div class="draft-container">
    <div class="draft-type"></div>
    <div class="draft-status"></div>
    <div class="start-time"></div>
</div>
<form method="POST" action="/comments">
    <input type="text" class="comment-box" name="comment_user" placeholder="test">
    <input type="textarea" class="comment-box" name="comment_content" placeholder="Leave a comment or talk some trash!">
    <button type="submit" class="comment-button">Comment</button>
</form>
<div class="comment-section">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close!

As `starters` is a list as well, then another `forEach` is needed to loop through the `starter` for every `item`.

Try the runnable example below. I used a subset of your elements in the example, specific to the javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.sleeper.app/v1/league/784456593403224064/rosters',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
            teamData = result.map(result => result.starters);
            teamData.forEach((starter, item) => {
                starter.forEach((entry) => { // loop the starter
                    $(`.starters-list${item}`).append('<li>'+entry+'</li>');
                });
            });
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="league-members-container">
    <div class="player-container">
        <img id="avatar0" src="" alt="">
        <div id="player0"></div>
        <div id="team-name0"></div>
            <ul class="starters-list0"></ul>
        </div>
        <br><br>

    <div class="player-container">    
        <img id="avatar1" src="" alt="">
        <div id="player1"></div>
        <div id="team-name1"></div>
        <ul class="starters-list1"></ul>
    </div> 
    <br><br>

    <div class="player-container">
        <img id="avatar2" src="" alt="">
        <div id="player2"></div>
        <div id="team-name2"></div>
        <ul class="starters-list2"></ul>
    </div>
    <br><br>

    <div class="player-container">
        <img id="avatar3" src="" alt="">
        <div id="player3"></div>
    <div id="team-name3"></div>
        <ul class="starters-list3"></ul>
    </div> 
    <br><br>

    <div class="player-container">
        <img id="avatar4" src="" alt="">
        <div id="player4"></div>
        <div id="team-name4"></div>
        <ul class="starters-list4"></ul>
    </div> 
    <br><br>

    <div class="player-container">
        <img id="avatar5" src="" alt="">
        <div id="player5"></div>
        <div id="team-name5"></div>
        <ul class="starters-list5"></ul>
    </div> 
    <br><br>

    <div class="player-container">
        <img id="avatar6" src="" alt="">
        <div id="player6"></div>
        <div id="team-name6"></div>
        <ul class="starters-list6"></ul>
    </div> 
    <br><br>

    <div class="player-container">
        <img id="avatar7" src="" alt="">
        <div id="player7"></div>
        <div id="team-name7"></div>
        <ul class="starters-list7"></ul>
    </div> 
    <br><br>

    <div class="player-container">
        <img id="avatar8" src="" alt="">
        <div id="player8"></div>        
        <div id="team-name8"></div>
        <ul class="starters-list8"></ul>
    </div> 
    <br><br>

    <div class="player-container">
        <img id="avatar9" src="" alt="">     
        <div id="player9"></div>        
        <div id="team-name9"></div>
        <ul class="starters-list9"></ul>  
    </div>    
</div>
```